# Is it possible for a filesystem type to be recognized differently or changed without reformatting a drive?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, apfs

When running `sudo fdisk -l` my EXT4 formatted SamsungQVO USB SSD now identifies as APFS.

```
Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda2  409640 3907029127 3906619488  1.8T Apple APFS
```

The disk was previously formatted APFS on macOS before formatting on a Linux computer as EXT4, to copy data from another EXT4 drive and use on a Raspi5 OS.

```
Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) aarch64
Host: Raspberry Pi 5 Model B Rev 1.0 
Kernel: 6.1.0-rpi6-rpi-2712
```

Not expecting the drive to be unrecognized, I created an entry in fstab and expected an error when running `mount -a` however it did not and after rebooting, is still mounted but recognized as APFS. The only thing which I changed in between was to move data on the disk.

Is there any possible explanation for this behavior or is it likely that I have inexplicably done something I'm not aware of?

Comment: Fdisk is showing the partition type, not the type of filesystem it contains - you can change that (using fdisk) without effecting the data the partition contains

Comment: What does `lsblk --output NAME,FSTYPE` say?

Comment: @Hermann ext4 thanks!

Comment: `fdisk /dev/sda` then enter `t` then `2` (if it asks for which partition, it may not if there's only one) - then `20` then `w`

Comment: @JaromandaX I see, I wasn't aware of that. Solved!

Comment: @JaromandaX please put that in an answer. (A) it can be accepted (B) your expertise can be more easily seen as comments can get deleted